# Acessing folders outside the workspace

Tags: java, directory, file-read

I've been searching for an answer to that for a while but without any success.
I am trying to load csv files into my program to work with them later on and I have the following issue.
When I try to access them directly from the place they are stored on my computer using absolute path :

```
File folder = new File("C:/Users/trybu/Desktop/AppData");

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    int filesNo = listOfFiles.length; //and so
```

it only works if I copy all of those files into my project workspace (I am using Eclipse).
But when I change the path name or move files (inside project) to another directory the files won't be read anymore. I find it really weird. Could someone explain that to me and maybe help me finding solution? Thanks!

Comment: Here's the general pattern that your question should have if you hope to get an answer: I want to do XXX. Here's what I tried: <code>. I expect this code to produce the following result: <expected result>, but instead it produces the following result: <actual result>. Provide all the necessary information why you think the code should produce the expected result. Avoid extremely vague problem descriptions such as "it won't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to use a proper path, in your code it looks like a combo of Windows and Unix format but I am not the expert on Windows path formats

Even better when handling paths and standard folders like the user home folder you can use a system property to get that path. The below code lists all files and folders in (on) the users Desktop

```
String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");

File desktop = new File(homeDir, "Desktop");

File[] fileList = desktop.listFiles();

for (File file : fileList) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

This was written and tested on a Mac but works equally well on Windows. Some more info on System property [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)